# Password strength check: comparing to previous passwords

Tags: cryptography, passwords

Every now and then I come across applications that force you to change passwords once in a while. Almost universally, they have this strange requirement for the new password: it has to be "significantly" different from your previous password(s).

While at first this sounds logical, next thing I think is: how do they do that? Do they store my passwords in plain text? I would have accepted the answer that they do, if it wasn't for the fact that these are kinds of applications that pretend to care about security so much they force you to change your password if it is expired! Microsoft Exchange is one example of this.

I'm not very good at cryptography and hash functions, so my question is this: Is it possible to enforce this kind of policy without storing passwords in plain text?

Do you know how this policy is implemented in real world applications?

**UPDATE**: An Example.
I was recently changing my Microsoft Exchange password. I only use Web Access, so it might be different a little -- I have no idea.
So, it forces me to change my password. What I do sometimes is I change it to something new and then change it back almost immediately. The freaky part is that It did not allow me to even change it back because of this. I tried changing it a little, by adding a letter in front of it or changing one symbol -- no luck, it was complaining.

Comment: Can you give an example of an application that exhibits this behaviour?  I can't say I've ever seen such a thing!

Comment: Applications that tell me what password to use are the ones I don't use.

Comment: @Oli I seem to remember that both Novell Netware and VAX VMS had this "feature", and very annoying it was too!

Comment: I believe Microsoft stores the hashes for the last N of your passwords, so they will not let you re-use one until you have gone through N different ones.  (They make us change our password every _six weeks_ where I work.  From personal experience, I know they have N set to at least 3 and at most 9...)

Comment: This question has been well answered over at [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3170/how-can-a-system-enforce-a-minimum-number-of-changed-characters-in-passwords-wit)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a typical hash, the best you can do is see if the new password is *exactly equal to* previous ones. You can break the password into multiple hashes in order to get more flexible with comparison, for example 3 hashes:

1. Alpha characters only
2. Numeric characters only
3. All other characters

You could for example require all the hashes to change to be accepted, to prevent users from just changing their password from `SecretPassword01` to `SecretPassword02`.

A cryptographic expert may weigh in here on if this could be made as secure as a single hash.

**NOTE** that this is **not** as secure as a single hash, so before you go implementing this, make sure you have really done your research.

Comment: A more general approach might be to store a hash of some canonical representation of the password just for this purpose. What is canonical representation is dependent on how similar passwords are defined. For example if the password is "abC" and one consider the password "Abc2" same as the original, he will store the hash of "abc#".

Comment: Hmm, this approach looks interesting. At the very least not as dumb as storing plain text passwords anyway :)

Comment: @Artium Awesome. Now I, the password cracker, only have to iterate through canonical representations until I get a match, then iterate through variations that generate the same representation. Much easier!

Comment: @Nick I agree that it makes things weaker. But still, as an attacker, you will have to obtain the passwords file first, and assuming that the canonical passwords space is large enough and uniform and that salts are involved, it is not much more easier task than cracking an ordinary passwords file. And after you discovered the canonical representation, you only get a hint about the password.

Comment: @Artium "You have to obtain the password file first" is an equally good (or rather, bad) argument for not hashing or salting your passwords at all. And if the canonical password space is large enough, why require users to use upper-case, numbers, or symbols at all?

Answer (score 7):

When changing password you're usually asked for the old one to confirm your identity. It's then trivial to compare the old one and the new one to see how much they differ. TBH I don't know how to compare to several previous passwords without storing them, but that's getting into the territory of ridiculous policies anyway.

Comment: Is my understanding correct that if you store only hashes, then it is impossible (as in, "designed to be impossible" or "very-very computationally hard") to do this?

Comment: @tenour: Er, how doesn't it answer the question?

Comment: @MaximSloyko: It's done before hashing anything, when you have passwords in the clear text, as input by the user.

Comment: I guess it's a fairly open-ended question and I interpreted it differently; ignore my comment :D

Comment: An improvement to this might be to encrypt the old passwords with the currently used one (which as you said, provided by the user). The problem I see with this is that there are time when all password history is available for hijack in the memory.