# Comparing with previous passwords

Tags: security, passwords, comparison

For security reasons, I need to force the user to change his password quite often and something I don't want is a password really close to the previous one, for obvious security reasons.

But for security reason as well, I can't keep the real password in the DB (ie: I need to hash it or any other method).
But I don't think comparing the hashes will help.

Is there a way to compare 2 passwords in order to know if they are close to each other?

Ex: password and password1 are too close to each other.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Password strength check: comparing to previous passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236542/password-strength-check-comparing-to-previous-passwords)

Comment: Also related: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3170/how-can-a-system-enforce-a-minimum-number-of-changed-characters-in-passwords-wi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time of making the user choose a new password, you make him/her enter his/her old password. This allows you to compare the new password to the old password without having to store the old password in plaintext.

Comment: easiest solution ;-) what if I need to reset my password, how do I enforce this rule in this special situation?

Answer (score 1):

When a user logs in normally you are storing a hash of the password in your database. You compare the password typed to the hash by hashing what they typed and if the resulting hash is the same as the hash in the database it is accepted.

To compare against old passwords you would do the same thing. You could save the last password (or the last 5, 10 ...x passwords) in the database by just copying the password hash field to old-password1 (shifting each password over one column if you want to keep them from reusing it after some number of changes, old-password1 becomes old-password2 etc) Then when they type in the new password you can compare the same way you always do, but against the old hashes. If it matches an old hash you reject it with a message saying that it cannot be one of the last X passwords they used.

You are not storing any clear-text passwords, and you can keep as many old hashes as you want.

Comment: YOu are not answering the question or i didnt understand what you mean.

Comment: ok, sorry. You are right what I suggested was to eliminate re-use of previous passwords, but you could also use this technique to store variations of the last password. 

Say the last password was Wednesday1 and you want to prevent Wednesday2, Wednesday3 etc. you could predict common variations (numbers added to the end, numbers in place of letters L33tSp3@k style...) and store the hashed version of those common variants. That requires a bit of extra storage space, but certainly it is doable.

Comment: It's not only this case, it was an example.